# Arranging Squares on a Quilt (with a bunch of rules)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

My wife is making a quilt. We are trying to figure out a way to arrange the squares that meets her aesthetic "requirements." I see a similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106148/need-randomness-within-constraints), but we've got two aspect variables and different rules. I'm wondering if somebody can work this out.

The squares:

- There are 126 squares.
- The squares come in 7 patterns (I will assign them numbers 1-7).
- Each pattern comes in 3 colors (but there are 5 colors total: white(w), red(r), light blue(b) teal(t), navy(n))
- For each pattern, there are 6 of each of its colors.

The break down is like this:

- Pattern 1: 1w, 1b, 1n
- Pattern 2: 2b, 2t, 2n
- Pattern 3: 3w, 3r, 3n
- Pattern 4: 4w, 4t, 4n
- Pattern 5: 5w, 5b, 5r
- Pattern 6: 6w, 6t, 6n
- Pattern 7: 7w, 7t, 7n

The rules:

- Making a quilt 9 squares by 14 squares
- No two squares of the same color can be adjacent (vertically or horizontally; diagonal is fine)
- No two squares of the same pattern (but different colors) can have fewer than 2 other patterns in between them, vertically or horizontally (so 1|2||,1 is fine; 1|2|1 or 1|1 are not).
- Squares of the same pattern AND color also must follow this rule, with the additional rule that they must have at least 1 square of a different pattern AND a different color between them diagonally.

Is this a solvable problem?

BONUS: She'd also be interested in a 11x11 arrangement and 10x12 arrangement with the same rules (though these would not use every square, of course - would appreciate the leftovers [5 and 6, respectively] each be a different pattern).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is typical constraint satisfaction problem which in your case can be formulated as a generalized cover set problem. Some condition should be satisfied exactly once (there is one and only one patch per place); some should be satisfied at most once (one or zero patches adjacent to the edge can be white); some conditions should be satisfied no more than 2 times (among patches on diagonal 1w 5w 1w, we can have any two of them, but not 3).

Unfortunately, I couldn't easily find the solver for a generalized cover set problem and I was too lazy to write it myself. So instead, I strengthened the last condition which is now:

- There should be at least 2 squares on the diagonal between two patches of same pattern and color

In that case, we don't have “no more than 2 times condition” and we can reformulate the problem in terms of graphs.

Consider all the possible placements of all the possible patches as nodes of a graph (21 patches × 9 rows × 14 columns = 2646 nodes). For example, node `1a1w` means row `1`, column `a`, pattern `1w`. Now, if two nodes share the placement or the rule, we connect them by an edge. For example, `5b1w—5b6t` (two patches cannot be at the same place); `5a4t-6a6t` (two adjacent patches cannot have the same color) etc.

By doing that, We will get a big graph (2646 nodes, 80081 edges):

[image]

In that graph we want to find an [independent set of vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)) of size 9×14. Luckily there is a function for that in Wolfram Mathematica.

Below I will show a couple of quilts I found, so your wife can choose the best-looking one:

```
9×14

2t 5b 4t 3r 2t 5r 7w 3n 5b 2t 3r 5b 2t 3r
5r 4w 2b 1w 5b 3w 2b 7t 3r 1b 2n 3w 5r 2b
1b 2t 5r 4t 1n 2t 3r 5w 2b 3w 5r 2b 3n 5w
3r 5b 1w 2n 3r 5b 7w 3n 5r 2t 1b 5w 2t 3r
2b 6w 3n 5b 2t 3w 5r 2b 3w 5b 2n 3r 5b 2n
1n 2t 5w 3r 6n 2b 3n 5w 6t 3r 5w 2b 3w 5r
3w 5r 1b 2t 5w 6t 1b 3r 5b 2n 1b 5r 2t 1b
5b 1n 3w 5r 2b 1w 5r 6n 2t 5r 3n 4w 5b 3r
1w 3r 2n 1b 3r 5b 6t 2b 3r 1n 2b 3r 1w 2b

5r 2b 3n 5r 1b 3n 5w 1b 2t 5r 1b 4n 2b 5r
1b 3r 5w 2b 3w 5r 2b 3r 1w 2b 6w 5b 3r 7t
2t 5b 6t 3r 5b 2t 1n 5b 3n 4t 5r 1n 6t 2b
3r 1w 2b 5w 7t 1b 3r 2t 5r 3w 1b 2t 5r 4t
5b 2t 3r 1n 2b 5r 4t 3n 1b 2t 3r 5b 4w 1b
2n 5r 1b 2t 5w 3n 1b 7t 3w 5b 2n 1w 7t 3w
1b 3w 7t 5b 1n 2b 3r 4w 5r 1w 6t 3n 2b 5r
5r 7n 2b 3w 7t 5r 4t 1b 2t 3r 1b 5r 3w 1b
2b 5w 3r 2t 5b 1w 2b 3r 1w 5b 3w 1n 5b 3r

2t 5r 1b 7t 5r 3w 2b 4t 3r 5w 1b 3r 5b 2t
5b 4t 3r 5w 2b 7t 3r 5b 4w 2b 5r 7t 2n 5r
3r 2b 7t 1b 3n 5r 1b 2t 5r 1w 2t 5b 3w 1n
7t 5r 1w 3r 7t 2b 4n 3r 2b 4t 1b 3r 4t 2b
1b 3w 2b 7n 5r 3w 2t 5b 1w 3n 5w 2b 1w 5r
3r 1n 5r 2t 1b 7n 5r 2n 3r 1b 2t 5r 6t 1b
2t 5b 1w 3r 7t 2b 3n 1b 6n 5r 3w 4t 2b 3r
1b 3r 2t 1b 3n 5r 2t 3r 5w 2b 4n 6w 5r 2t
5r 2b 3w 5r 2b 4t 5b 2n 1b 3r 5b 2t 6n 5b

5r 2b 7t 1b 3r 2b 5r 7t 1b 6t 3r 2t 1n 3r
1b 4t 3r 2n 5b 4t 1b 3r 7n 2b 6n 3w 2b 7n
2t 5r 1n 3w 2t 5r 3w 1n 6t 3r 2t 5b 3n 1b
5b 1w 2b 5r 3n 2b 7t 5r 2b 6n 5r 2n 6t 3r
3r 6t 5w 1b 4t 3r 5b 6w 3r 2t 1b 3w 5r 2t
7w 5b 3r 6t 5b 7t 3w 1b 6t 5b 3r 6t 2b 5w
5r 7t 1b 5w 3r 2b 6n 5r 1w 6n 2b 5r 4t 3r
1b 3w 5r 2b 6t 5r 7t 6w 5b 3r 7t 1b 5w 2t
3r 5b 7t 3r 5b 6w 2b 3r 6t 1b 5r 2t 3r 5b

11×11

6w 3r 5w 1b 3r 2t 5r 1b 7t 5b 2t
5b 1n 4t 3w 6t 1n 2b 6t 5w 3r 1b
3r 6w 1b 5r 2b 3r 4t 5r 1b 2t 5r
6t 5b 3r 6t 1w 5b 7w 2b 4t 5w 2b
5r 3w 4t 2b 5r 7t 3r 1w 5b 3r 7t
2t 1b 5w 7t 3n 1b 6w 5r 2t 6w 5b
3r 7w 2b 5r 1w 3r 7t 6n 1b 5r 6t
7t 5r 3w 1n 5b 7n 1b 3r 6t 2b 3r
5b 3n 1b 7t 3r 1w 6t 2n 5b 3n 2t
3r 1w 5r 3w 1n 5b 3r 1b 2t 5r 1b
4t 5b 3n 1b 5r 6t 2b 5r 7n 2b 3r

5r 1b 6w 3r 2b 5r 3w 2b 6t 1b 2t
2b 3r 7t 5w 1n 2t 5b 4t 2n 5r 4w
3w 5b 1w 2n 5b 6w 2n 3r 5b 2t 7n
5r 2t 3r 1b 2t 5r 1w 2b 4t 3w 5r
2b 3w 6t 5r 3w 2b 6t 5r 1b 6t 2b
6w 5r 2b 6n 1b 3r 5b 6n 2t 5b 3r
5b 6t 3r 4t 5r 6t 2n 4t 5r 3n 4t
3r 1b 5w 2b 4n 5b 3r 2b 4n 1b 2n
6t 5r 2t 3r 7t 2n 1b 5w 3r 2t 5b
5b 3w 1b 5w 2b 4t 5r 3n 2b 5w 3r
3r 2b 5r 4t 3r 5b 2t 1b 5r 3n 1b

3r 2b 5r 1n 6t 2b 5r 7t 2b 5r 3n
5b 1w 6t 2b 3r 1w 2t 5b 3r 6w 5b
2t 5r 1b 3n 4t 5b 3n 6t 5w 2b 6t
1b 6n 2t 5r 1b 2t 5r 1b 6n 5r 3w
6t 3r 5b 1n 6t 3r 2b 7t 3r 4t 5b
5r 1b 6n 4t 2n 5b 1w 2n 5b 3w 2t
2b 6t 3r 2b 5r 6t 3n 5r 1w 2b 3n
1w 5b 2t 6n 1b 3r 2t 1b 3n 5r 1b
5r 2n 1b 3r 6t 2n 5b 3r 6t 1n 5w
2b 4t 5r 1w 2b 5r 3w 2b 5w 3r 2b
3r 1b 2t 5b 3r 1b 2t 5r 1b 2t 7w

2b 6n 5r 2n 1b 5r 7n 1b 2t 3w 5b
3r 7t 2b 5w 3r 2b 6t 5r 7n 1b 3r
1b 5w 3n 1b 2t 3w 5b 2n 3r 5w 2b
5r 2b 1w 3r 5b 6t 1w 7t 2b 3n 5r
6t 3r 5b 2n 7t 5w 2b 3r 5w 2t 1b
1b 7n 2t 5r 1b 3n 5r 2t 1b 5r 4w
7t 2b 1w 7n 3r 2t 1w 5b 3r 4t 5b
5b 3r 7t 2b 5w 1n 2b 4t 5w 1b 3r
2n 1b 5w 3r 1b 5r 4n 3r 2t 5r 7t
3r 2t 1n 5b 2t 4w 5b 2n 1b 3w 5b
1b 5r 2b 1w 5r 2b 3r 1w 5r 2b 3r

10×12

5r 2b 7n 3r 4t 5r 2b 4t 5r 2b 3w 5b
6t 3r 4w 6t 5w 1b 7t 5b 3n 1w 5r 2n
3w 7t 5b 4n 3r 6t 5w 2t 1b 3r 2t 1b
2t 5w 3r 2b 1w 5r 2b 3r 5w 2b 1n 3r
5r 2b 4t 3w 2t 1b 6t 5b 2n 1w 5b 2t
1b 3r 5w 1b 6w 4t 5r 2t 1b 5r 2n 1b
3w 1n 2b 5r 1n 3r 2b 1n 3r 2b 1w 3r
2t 5b 3r 2t 5b 6t 3n 5b 2t 3w 5b 2t
5r 3n 7t 1b 3n 2b 5r 3w 1b 5r 4t 1b
3w 2b 4n 5r 2t 3r 7t 2b 3r 6t 2b 5r

5b 2t 3r 5b 1w 3r 2t 5r 6w 1b 3r 5b
3r 5w 2b 3w 5r 1b 3w 2b 7t 5r 2n 7t
2b 3n 5r 1n 2b 7t 5r 6t 1b 2t 5b 3r
5w 1b 3w 5b 7w 3r 2b 7n 5r 3n 6t 2b
3n 5r 2t 3r 1b 2n 7w 3r 2b 7t 3w 5r
2b 7t 5b 1w 3n 7t 1n 5b 4t 2n 5b 1w
5r 1b 3r 2t 5w 1b 3r 2t 5r 1b 4t 2b
3w 2t 1w 5r 2b 3n 5b 1n 2b 4w 1n 5r
2b 3r 5b 1n 3w 5r 2t 3w 4n 5b 3r 7t
5r 1b 2t 3r 1b 7t 3r 5b 1w 3n 5w 2b

3r 2b 5r 1w 3r 2b 5r 1w 2b 5r 6t 2b
5b 3w 1b 2n 5b 7w 2t 5b 3r 7t 5b 3r
2t 5r 4t 3r 2t 5r 1b 7n 5w 3n 2t 1b
3r 1b 5w 7t 3w 2b 7t 3r 6t 2b 3w 5r
5b 7t 3r 5b 1n 6t 5r 2b 4n 5r 6t 2b
7w 5r 1b 2t 5r 3n 1b 6t 3r 4t 5b 3r
1b 2t 5w 3r 2b 5w 3r 1n 5b 3n 2t 5w
5r 3n 2b 7t 3w 1b 6t 2b 4t 5r 3w 2b
2b 5w 3r 1b 5r 2n 1w 5r 6w 1b 4t 3r
3r 2t 5b 3w 2t 5b 3r 6t 5b 3r 1w 5b

5b 4t 1b 2t 5r 1b 2n 5b 3r 2t 1b 5r
3w 2b 5r 1n 2b 3w 5r 2t 1w 5b 3r 2b
4t 3r 2n 5b 4t 2n 1b 3r 2b 1n 5w 3n
2n 5b 4t 3r 1b 5r 2t 1n 5w 3r 1b 5r
3r 2t 5r 4n 2t 1w 3r 2b 4t 5b 3w 2b
5w 4n 2b 1w 3n 4t 5b 6t 3r 2t 5r 3n
2b 1w 3n 5r 1b 3r 4n 1b 5w 3n 2b 5w
4w 3r 5b 2t 4w 5b 7t 3w 2b 5r 3w 1b
5r 2b 4t 1b 3r 4t 2b 5r 3n 2t 5b 3r
7t 4n 3w 5r 2t 1b 3r 2t 5b 3r 7t 5w
```

Comment: At first glance, I thought this was right, but now I realize there's a key factor missing from your matrices, the fourth bullet of the info on squares - there are only 6 instances of each  pattern/color combo.
So in the 9x14 grids every combo should appear exactly six times, but in your grids some show up more than 6 times, some not at all, etc.

Comment: I missed that restriction. However, with that restriction, I wasn't able to find the independent see of size 126. Max size I got was 108. Maybe, the approximate solver I use fails on a large graph, maybe the strengthened diagonal condition is too harsh, maybe the initial problem has no solution.

Comment: Any chance you could link me to the tools you used and how you input the data? I think I follow the basic premise enough to mess around with it if I knew where the various inputs were plugged in and into what, but not enough to know how to set the 'rules' for finding independent sets or how to use an approximate solver. Alternatively, I understand it so little that what I just wrote makes no sense.

Comment: Alternatively, if it can do 108 in a 9x12 grid, I'd be interested in seeing that. Maybe we'll get lucky and can do the last row of a 10x12 by eye.